# How to find relationship between two different stereo calibrations

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, point-clouds, stereo-3d

I have a question for you.

I have performed a single and stereo calibration using 10 different checkerboard poses. I have acquired a image pair and obtained the 3D position of each pixel and saved in a point cloud (PCL).

After that, I have performed another calibration using 60 different checkerboard poses. The obtained calibration parameters are different from those estimated in the previous calibration.

I have used the same image pair to obtain the point cloud and get the 3D reconstruction of the scene and I notice that the corresponding 3D points in the two point clouds have different location in the space.

When the two point clouds are displayed in MeshLab, two separate point clouds in the space are represented.

I think that the origin of the "reconstructed space" is changed somehow according to calibration parameters.

How can I get the transformation between the two different coordinates system so that, known the transformation, I can display the second and the first point clouds overlapping?

The aim is to find this relationship using only stereo-calibration parameters. I know that the transformation could be computed using the correspondences between the same points displayed in the two point clouds, but I need to find out this relationship using only the calibration parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: *The obtained calibration parameters are different from those estimated in the previous calibration.* what parameters are you referring to? Intrinsic?

Comment: Both the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. Also the Q matrix used to compute the 3D position of the points of the scene is different from the one obtained in the first calibration.